# How to know if the android request permission dialog is shown

Tags: android, react-native

Here shows the example on how to use PersmissionAndroid in react native:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera")
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

1. How to know if this dialog is really shown? Because there are times that the user has already approved the permission and the next it call this functions, it will not show anymore and just return the granted results.
2. How to know if the user has really clicked on the Deny and Allow buttons?

Comment: This is exactly what PermissionsAndroid.request() does. I mean you could return the results (const granted) and save them in your state/store/localStorage, but why?

Comment: why do i have to save them in the local storage?